# change old signalR hub to new version

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I have chat sample using the old signalr dll version[0.5.3] and I want to make it in the new AspNet.SignalR library version 2.2.0
the old sample have `Clients[chatRoom.chatRoomId].` where the Clients was a dynamic property in hub class.
but in the new hub the Clients is not dybamic.

How can I fix it in the new version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what your `chatRoomId` is: if it is a group identifier, as I would assume, you just need to do this:

```
Clients.Groups(chatRoom.chatRoomId). ...
```

and there you have your dynamic object. In general, `Clients` has become a container for more specific groups, like `All`, `Others`, `Caller`, etc. Those ones are dynamic and can be used as you were used to before. Check [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromhub).